# How to convert a PostgreSQL CTE to KnexJS

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I would like to understand how I can convert the following raw Psql into a KnexJS method

```sql
WITH selected_studies AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        candidates
    WHERE
        day = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')
        AND study_id IN('RECOV')
) INSERT INTO candidates ("day", "study_id", "site_id", "status", "total", "current", "referrer_token", "total_ids", "current_ids")
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "study_id", "site_id", "status", "total", "current", "referrer_token", "total_ids", "current_ids"
FROM
    selected_studies
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            candidates
        WHERE
            day = CURRENT_DATE);
```

The method function is to copy all data from a day before where the `studyIds` are matching and insert the copy in the same table, the row, but if not already exist.

I've been trying with the documentation to do it but I'm lost. I would like to avoid as much as possible the raw Psql.

I tried so far as follow but it doesn't work

```
async createBaselineForToday({ studyIds }) {
    const now = new Date();

    const todaysDate = beginningOfDay(now);
    const yesterdaysDate = beginningOfDayBefore(now);

    const whereRow = prepare({
      day: todaysDate,
      studyId: columns.studyId,
      siteId: columns.siteId,
      status: columns.status,
      total: columns.total,
      current: columns.current,
      referrerToken: columns.referrerToken,
      totalIds: columns.totalIds,
      currentIds: columns.currentIds,
    });

    return this.tx
      .with('select_data_before', qb => {
        qb.select('*').from(tableName).whereIn(columns.studyId, studyIds).where(columns.day, yesterdaysDate);
      })
      .insert({ ...whereRow })
      .select({
        day: todaysDate,
        studyId: columns.studyId,
        siteId: columns.siteId,
        status: columns.status,
        total: columns.total,
        current: columns.current,
        referrerToken: columns.referrerToken,
        totalIds: columns.totalIds,
        currentIds: columns.currentIds,
      })
      .from('select_data_before')
      .whereNotExists(function exists(ex) {
        ex.select(1).from(tableName).where(columns.day, todaysDate);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you are going to be able to avoid using a fair amount of `knex.raw` for that specific statement.

The first part that is going to require a fair amount of raw sql is the CTE definition, I don't believe there is a way round this at the moment.

The other area that will use some quite ugly looking raw sql (ugly due to all the parameter binding) is in the select statement after the insert. There just doesn't seem to be a nice way of doing an insert from a select query in knex yet.

This should be a translation of your original raw psql statement

```js
knex.with(
    'selected_studies',
    knex.raw(`
    SELECT * FROM candidates
    WHERE
    day = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')
    AND study_id IN('RECOV')
    `)
)
    .into(knex.raw('?? (??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??)', ['candidates', 'day', 'study_id', 'site_id', 'status', 'total', 'current', 'referrer_token', 'total_ids', 'current_ids']))
    .insert(knex.select([knex.fn.now(), 'study_id', 'site_id', 'status', 'total', 'current', 'referrer_token', 'total_ids', 'current_ids'])
        .from('selected_studies')
        .whereNotExists(function () {
            this.from('candidates')
                .where('day', knex.fn.now());
        }));
```

If you are confident about the origin of your data and are not worried about escaping or injection you could remove the argument bindings from the `.into()` call and just pass values straight in